# image data generator +Auto labeling +Auto plots bounding boxes based on object segmentation

Tags: opencv, image-processing

To create the labelled image data sets based on image segmentation , is there any tool available for Auto labeling + Auto plotting the bounding boxes based on object segmentation with just images as the input with no manual efforts?

Swati

Answer (score 0):

Auto labeling is not possible because you are already trying to label to find that label. So its not possible in your own images.

### BUT

You can crop your desired box and copy it to different background in different rotation by using [opencv_createsamples](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html#opencv-createsamples-utility). This is really usefull.

Here is the reference [link](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/).

Here is also an [article](https://machinelearning.technicacuriosa.com/2019/10/09/pain-label/) for inspiration.